# Jest not.toThrowError() not working in test with jest.spyOn(component.methods, 'mymethod')

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, nuxt.js, vue-test-utils

I am trying to make a test for my Nuxt/Vue component method that checks whether or not there was an error.

So what I have done is created a "spy" for this method of interest `const spyGetNumberOfResults = jest.spyOn(SearchTable.methods, 'getNumberOfResults')`, and then I am expecting it `expect(spyGetNumberOfResults).not.toThrowError()`, however I am getting an odd error, where it's saying one of my variables inside my method of interest is undefined. This is the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'countLoading' of undefined

      571 |         async getNumberOfResults () {
      572 |             // Kick off loader to signal retrieving counts
    > 573 |             this.countLoading = true;
          | ^
      574 | 
      575 |             // Initialize count
      576 |             this.count = '';

      at getNumberOfResults (components/core/SearchTable.vue:573:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/expect/build/toThrowMatchers.js:81:11)
      at Object.toThrowError (node_modules/expect/build/index.js:342:33)
      at Object.<anonymous> (test/SearchTable.spec.js:150:57)
```

and this is my test code:

```
test(`GET /${MODEL[1][MAIN_MODULES[i]].subModules[j].backEndFilters.mainModule}/${MODEL[1][MAIN_MODULES[i]].subModules[j].backEndFilters.subModule}/`, async () => {
    const API_ENDPOINT = process.env.NODE_ENV;
    // Initialize our variables
    let success = '';
    let responseData;
    let url = `${API_ENDPOINT}${store.state.core.group.current.id}/${MODEL[1][MAIN_MODULES[i]].subModules[j].backEndFilters.mainModule}/${MODEL[1][MAIN_MODULES[i]].subModules[j].backEndFilters.subModule}?${MODEL[1][MAIN_MODULES[i]].subModules[j].backEndFilters.limit}&fields=`;
    
    // Add fields/columns to be searched on to url
    MODEL[1][MAIN_MODULES[i]].subModules[j].allHeaders.map((header) => {
        if (header.active === true) {
            url += header.value + ',';
        }
    });

    // Remove trailing comma so the sql query doesn't break
    url = url.slice(0, -1);
    
    // Send HTTP GET request
    await axios.get(url, { headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("access-token")}` } })
        .then(response => {
            success = response.data.success;
            responseData = response;
        })
        .catch(error => console.log('Error:', error));
    
    // Check if HTTP request was successful
    expect(success).toBe(true);

    // Set-up wrapper options
    const wrapperOptions = {
        localVue,
        propsData: {
            searchModule: MODEL[1][MAIN_MODULES[i]].subModules[j],
            query: 'test'
        },
        mocks: {
            $axios: {
                create: () => {
                    return {
                        baseURL: API_ENDPOINT,
                        headers: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("access-token")}`,
                        get: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve(responseData))
                    };
                },
            }
        }
    };
    
    // Prep spies for our component methods we want to validate
    const spyGetNumberOfResults = jest.spyOn(SearchTable.methods, 'getNumberOfResults');
    const spySearch = jest.spyOn(SearchTable.methods, 'search');

    // Mount the component we're testing
    const wrapper = mount(SearchTable, wrapperOptions);

    // Set component data variable
    wrapper.setData({
        count: 0,
        countLoading: false,
        // If true, debug lines log to console, else they don't, set to false prior to release
        debug: false,
        dialog: false,
        intraTableDialog: false,
        expanded: [],
        expandableDataCheck: false,
        frontEndFilters: [],
        itemsOnScreen: null,
        generalSearch: '',
        ignoreCount: false,
        // Set this to true for the test
        regen: true,
        results: [],
        strictSearch: false,
        selectedColumnHeaders: [],
        stagedHeaders: [],
        correctStagedHeaders: [],
        selected: [],
        tableLoading: false,
        intraTableQuery: ''
    })

    // Trigger initial search method to get # of results
    wrapper.vm.getNumberOfResults();

    // Wait for DOM to update
    await wrapper.vm.$nextTick();
    
    // Check if the method was actually called
    expect(spyGetNumberOfResults).toHaveBeenCalled();
    
    // Expect no error from the promise in the function
    expect(spyGetNumberOfResults).not.toThrowError();

    // Expect there the count to be greater than or equal to 0
    expect(parseInt(wrapper.vm.count)).toBeGreaterThanOrEqual(0);

    // Wait for DOM to update
    await wrapper.vm.$nextTick();

    // Check to see if the "search" method was triggered after receiving results
    expect(spySearch).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

However, if I just comment out the line:

```
expect(spyGetNumberOfResults).not.toThrowError();
```

I get no errors and my test passes, so there is clearly something wrong with how I am using "not.toThrowError()", but the error message is not very informative to me, someone suggested I add {"loose": true} to my .babelrc config file but this did nothing, I am new to Jest and don't know why this is happening, any assistance is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

`toThrowError` or `not.toThrowError` must be called not on the spy function. There is good example from [docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#tothrowerror):

```
test('throws an error', () => {
  expect(() => {
    SearchTable.getNumberOfResults(); // There must be your call
  }).toThrow();
});
```

Comment: Yes, spyOn, or jest, will automatically call that method AGAIN if you are checking toThrowError() - so instead use Eduardo's solution above. You can still have spyOn enabled, and check additional things after this first expect statement. Basically, if you're going to check Throws, start with the throw check first to run your function, then check anything else.